# Show String contents in the OQL result when using MAT

Tags: java, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer, oql

When I execute the following OQL in Eclipse Memory Analyzer

```
SELECT key FROM com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$StrongAccessWriteEntry
```

I got the following result

```
key
---------------------------------
java.lang.String [id=0x7bfa42f80]
java.lang.String [id=0x7bdf3a5b0]
java.lang.String [id=0x7bdf380c0]
java.lang.String [id=0x7bdf175e0]
......
---------------------------------
```

I can check out the value of each result row by right-clicking it and select `List Objects -> with outgoing references`, that is not convenient. I want the result to be like this:

```
key
---------------------------------
java.lang.String [id=0x7bfa42f80]  apple
java.lang.String [id=0x7bdf3a5b0]  peach
java.lang.String [id=0x7bdf380c0]  pineapple
java.lang.String [id=0x7bdf175e0]  cherry
......
---------------------------------
```

Assuming `apple`, `peach`, `pineapple`, `cherry` is the contents of each row.

In this way, I'm able to know the value of each row just by looking at it. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just use the following command

```
SELECT key.toString() FROM com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$StrongAccessWriteEntry
```